# How to extend property of ComponentPublicInstance provided by Vue 3 in a certain vue file

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I want add a custom property to ComponentPublicInstance.
Example, I have a Vue file. It is using Vue 3 Composition API with `<script setup lang='ts'>` and I declared a Function, like this:

```
<script setup lang='ts'>
  function close() {
    console.log("It will be closed")
  }
</script>
```

I redner this file by `render` porvided by vue, and this is part of my code:

```
export const Notification = function (options: Options){
  const container = document.createElement('div')
  const vnode = h(notification, {...options}) 
  // The Render contribute to make vnode processing diff and patch and then mounted on the Container
  render(vnode, container)
  const instance = vnode.component?.proxy
  addIntance(vnode.component as ComponentInternalInstance)
  console.log("vnode.component", vnode.component)
  return instance
} as NotificationProperty
```

There is an Array named `instanceList` saving the instance of Notification, and I want to call the `close` in the instance, and I got a error `Property 'close' does not exist on type 'ComponentPublicInstance<{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, false, ComponentOptionsBase<any, any, any, any, any, any, any, any, any, {}>>'.`.
This is my code:

```
Notification.closeAll = function () {
  instanceList.forEach((instance: ComponentInternalInstance, index: number) => {
    instance.proxy?.close() // There is an error.
    instanceList.splice(1, index)
  })
}
```

I have tried to use the methods following.

1. using `defineExpose` to export `close` function.
2. to declare a module in the `shims-vue.d.ts`

```
declare module "./components/notification/Notification.vue" { 
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    close: () => any;
  }
}
```

or

```
declare module "@vue/runtime-core" { 
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    close: () => any;
  }
}
```

Both are not working.

Now, I have no idea how to cope with the problem.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try [defineExpose](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose)

Comment: I tried it. The error is still in there.`<script setup lang='ts'>
  import { defineExpose } from 'vue'
  function close() {
    console.log("It will be closed")
  }

  defineExpose({ close })
</script>`